# Cancel button flickers when typing into New Contact text fields

Tags: ios, swift, contacts, flicker

Summary: In the Swift sample app from Apple, ManagingContactsUI, the Cancel button on the left side of the New Contact screen's navigation bar flickers when the user types into any of the text controls. The app was built with Swift 4 and XCode 9.2. Run the application on either a real device running iOS 11.x or the Simulator (iPhone  6 - 8 were used).

Steps to Reproduce:

1. Build and launch the app generated from the ManagingContactsUI
   sample app, ContactViewController.
2. Tap the "Create New Contact"
   item.
3. Tap the First Name text entry control and begin typing. Notice
   the Cancel button in the top-left corner of the New Contact screen
   begins to flicker.

Expected Results: Cancel button should not flicker while typing.

Actual Results:
Cancel button flickers while user types into any of the text fields.

Version/Build:
Version 1.0, 2017-07-20

Configuration:
iPhone 5s through 7, running iOS 9.3 through iOS 11.2.2. Simulator for iPhone 6 through 8, deployment targets included 9.3, 10.3 and 11.2.

Development environment:
15" Macbook Pro running High Sierra 10.13.2
XCode v9.2, Swift 4

I sent this exact question/bug report to Apple Developer Portal and have heard nothing (2 weeks ago). I use this feature, Contacts Framework, in my commercial applications and use the exact coding method as shown in Apple's  sample application. My customers are complaining about the flickering of the Cancel button and are asking to have it fixed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.[Link to ManagingContactsUI sample app code](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/ManagingContactsUI/Introduction/Intro.html)